# What is the best way to filter my SQL queries to search for a certain "top" parent?

Tags: sql, nhibernate, recursion

I have a website that uses nhibernate that is querying a SQL server database. One of the tables has the following columns:

ID
Name
ParentId

So some entries in this table might be might be:

Id Name ParentId
1, "Joe", 3
3, "Tim", 5
5, "Jack", 7
7, "Tom", null

I am trying to run a query like this (pseudo SQL) . .

```
 "Select * from ThisTable where IsDescendant of 7"
```

and this would return any children of 7 or children of children, etc . . (in this example above, all rows would be returned)

What is the best way to right this without having to keeping everything in the loop.  Also, since i am using nhibernate I can add this as a function in my code but it looks like it translates to hundreds of SQL statements.  I am also curious how to do this in raw SQL as well.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer2005+ you can use recursive CTE

```
DECLARE @Id int = 7     
;WITH cte AS
  (
   SELECT Id, Name, ParentId
   FROM dbo.test45
   WHERE Id = @Id
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.Id, t.Name, t.ParentId
   FROM dbo.test45 t JOIN cte c On t.ParentId = c.Id
   )
   SELECT *
   FROM cte
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8323/3)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a table that holds the calculated descendants over multiple levels to all entries in the table you were referring.
Using CTE should be quite effective, though if you query the descendants very often you can greatly reduce the databases overhead if you write out all descendance data in a seperate table that would have a structure like this:

Table XDescendance:
ID, ItemID, ParentID, Level

You would then let this data be rewritten when a trigger on that table notices any changes.

Then you can query this almost exactly as you wrote it (well almost)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        ThisTable.*
    FROM ThisTable
    INNER JOIN XDescendance
        ON ThisTable.ID = XDescendance.ItemID
        AND XDescendance.ParentID = 7
```